# CQL 3 Unable to Create Column Family With Randomized Name

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

When shelled into my Cassandra instance via cqlsh, I am able to create a CF using

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY IF NOT EXISTS 
  sandbox.foo
  ( created TIMESTAMP, 
    updated TIMESTAMP,  
    PRIMARY KEY (created) )  ;
```

but when I run

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY IF NOT EXISTS 
  sandbox.6f4922f45568161a8
  ( created TIMESTAMP, 
    updated TIMESTAMP,  
    PRIMARY KEY (created) ) ;
```

The command fails w/ error `SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 3:2 no viable alternative at input '(' (... IF NOT EXISTS   sandbox.6f4922f45568161a8  [(]...)">`.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The [`CREATE TABLE` documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html) is pretty clear on this one:

> Valid table names are strings of alphanumeric characters and underscores, **which begin with a letter**.

Try placing a (random?) letter at the beginning of your table name, and then it should work.

Comment: That is exactly what I missed - prepending a `cf` to the generated CF names fixed the issue - thanks!